DC Motor Controller using "Force Control" in WeBots
i'm trying to develop a Webots torque controller to simulate the exact behaviour of a servomotor, using the dynamics equations of a DC Motor and a PID, controller. My robot works perfectly with the Position Controll mode of all joints, but with the torque controller, the robot explodes. All the parameters of the DC servomotor where obtained usign the Parameter Estimation Tool from Simulink.

KP = 0.5
KD = 0#0.00019425
KI = 0#0.013507
KM = 0.0020
RA = 1.45
LA = 0.00019652

def computeTorques():
    global joint, joint_angular_velocity, joint_sensor, joint_angular_position
    global prev_joint_angular_position, joint_torque, error, delta_error, acum_error
    global prev_error, Ia, enable_torque_control
    print("New Simulation Step")
    if enable_torque_control == 0:
       return
    MAX_TORQUE = 3.43  # Limit torque to the motor's max capacity
    DAMPING_FACTOR = 0  # Optional damping
    ALPHA = 0  # Low-pass filter for velocity

    for i in range(len(joint)):
        # Get position and compute velocity with smoothing
        joint_angular_position[i] = joint_sensor[i].getValue()
        print("Angular Position %d: %f" % (i, joint_angular_position[i]))
        print("Previous Angular Position %d: %f" % (i,prev_joint_angular_position[i]))
        raw_velocity = (joint_angular_position[i] - prev_joint_angular_position[i]) / (timestep * 1e-3)
        joint_angular_velocity[i] = ALPHA * joint_angular_velocity[i] + (1 - ALPHA) * raw_velocity
        prev_joint_angular_position[i] = joint_angular_position[i]

    # PID control
    error = target_joint - joint_angular_position
    delta_error = (error - prev_error) / (timestep * 1e-3)
    acum_error += error * timestep * 1e-3
    prev_error = error

    # Voltage and current calculations
    VA = KP * error + KD * delta_error + KI * acum_error
    Eb = joint_angular_velocity * 373 * KM
    Ia = (VA - Eb) / RA

    # Torque calculation
    joint_torque = Ia * KM * 373
    joint_torque = np.clip(joint_torque - DAMPING_FACTOR * joint_angular_velocity, -MAX_TORQUE, MAX_TORQUE)


    print("VA", VA)
    print("Eb", Eb)
    
    print("Omega", joint_angular_velocity)  
    #print("dI_dt", dI_dt)
    #print("Ia", Ia)
    print("joint_torque", joint_torque)
    # Apply torque to joints
    for i in range(len(joint)):
        joint[i].setTorque(joint_torque[i])
        #print("Torque %d: %f" %(i,joint[i].getTorqueFeedback()))

What I'm seeing is that the angular velocities of the joints are too high between simulations step, thus making the computed torques to be very high. This does not happen in position controll mode.
